# Why is the bounce rate high and how do I improve it?

Tags: google-analytics, website-design, analytics, bounce-rate

I recently launched a site for reviews on mobile application games and after a couple weeks of running it I have a really high bounce rate 92%. I was just wondering if anyone could have a look at my site and give me your thoughts on it and how I could improve this bounce rate it would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey the site is not responsive is it? What is the share of mobile traffic that you are getting on this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Bounce rate is the factor that indicates the ratio between number of visitors viewing only one page of your site and the number of entries to our site. If you get high bounce rate means viewers are closing your site without viewing more pages and spending less time in your site. I saw your site and it looks nice. I have a question for you
1. ***Did you submit your website's link on other unwanted, irrelevant websites?*** if you did so then your bounce rate will surely increase and also your website ranking will decrease. If you have low quality or irrelevant apps in your site, your websites bounce rate will increase.

**Methods to reduce bounce rate:**

1.In order to decrease your bounce rate, check all backlinks of your website. Use back link checker tool and filter and remove irrelevant and unwanted backlinks that targets your website.

2.Go to webmaster tool and Click Traffic and again click 'links to your site' option. You will find all your internal backlinks. Remove all the unwanted backlinks if you have authority otherwise just Disavow all those thinks using Google disavow tool ( https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fwebmasters%2Ftools%2Fdisavow-links-main%3Fpli%3D1&ei=UXqtUbT_M4-IrAf3uYGIBg&usg=AFQjCNHQtgJnBhcFrPSIcWWzisTQNsRd3w&sig2=UAN3Nmm2EGh-kYtekA-tUg&bvm=bv.47244034,d.bmk )

3.Don't Open and close your webpage frequently without viewing more pages because while calculating bounce rate Google would calculate your own page views ( Direct Visit ) also.

3.Provide user friendly and user likeable content and games in your website

If you do all those thinks your website's bounce rate will surely decrease.

All the best

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot, I'm definitely working on that now.

Answer (score 1):

- It has a nice, clean design with good user experience. Did you test it in different browsers? If not, here's a link to a browser screen shot site: [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/)
- If JavaScript is turned off, you're not going to see any content at all. You might add [Noscript tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp)s with a link to an HTML version. That also might help with some search engines that don't crawl JS well if you include them in your sitemap.
- Reviewing the content from the perspective of a visitor, my thoughts were:

  - What kind of apps (e.g., Android/iPhone, Chrome, etc...)?
  - Although the reviews looked good, why so few apps listed? People are used to seeing thousands in the Playstore, iTunes, Chrome Web Store...
  - Related to the above, you should add some content that helps differentiate you from other sites, what makes it unique or of value, and explains the focus of your site. For example, a simple H1 tag might with something like: "In-depth reviews of the latest, hotest apps to save you time..." would go far to add value to your site and peak interest to stay on it longer.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that, thanks for the very good input!